# multithreading do not work togather

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-multithreading

I am using PyQt4 and Python 2.7.

I have two functions to start up at the same time. But the second function doesn't start up until the first ends.

What is going wrong?

```
def testvision():
    x=5
    while x>0:
        print 'vision'
        time.sleep(1)
        x=x-1
    print 'finish vision'

def testforword():
    x=5
    while x>0:
        print 'froword'
        time.sleep(1)
        x=x-1
    print 'finish forword'

def Forword_thread(self):

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=testvision())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=testforword())
    t1.start()

    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

I call the function in this way:

```
self.pushbuttonForword.clicked.connect(self.Forword_thread)
```

[image]

Comment: please post your code rather than images - no-one can recreate your problem if we can't run it

Comment: The majority of your code is still in a picture. A single line of code helps no one. The error in your code is not in the line of text you have provided. Please provide a [MCVE] that can be copied and pasted as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your creating your threads like this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=testvision())
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
target = testvision()                 # returns None, so target is None now
t1 = threading.Thread(target=target)  # passes None as target
```

That means the function `testvision()` is executed in the current thread, the new thread is created with an empty target method, which is the same as using `Thread()`. When started, this thread will invoke its (empty) `run()` method and exit immediately.

The correct way would be to use

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=testvision)
```

Same for `t2`.